# TensorFlow: How to write the word-embeddings to a file

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec, word-embedding

I'm new to TF. I was following a a tutorial which I found online. The tutorial builds word-embeddings and then computes the similarity between words (for a given set) using the cosine sim. What I was trying to do is to store the generated word-embeddings to a file.

Below is the code (snippets) :

```
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0)) 
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, input_word_index_list)   

weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size,embedding_size],stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))
hidden_out = tf.matmul(embed,tf.transpose(weights)) + biases


train_one_hot = tf.one_hot(train_context, vocabulary_size)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=hidden_out, labels=train_one_hot))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(cross_entropy)

...
...

norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keep_dims=True))
normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm

final_embeddings = normalized_embeddings.eval()

for keys in reverse_dictionary_dict:
    embedings_to_file = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(final_embeddings,keys)
    writeEmbeddings2File.write(str(keys)+'\t'+ str(reverse_dictionary_dict[keys])+'\t'+tf.Print(embedings_to_file,embedings_to_file))
    writeEmbeddings2File.write('\n')
writeEmbeddings2File.close()
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Expected list for 'data' argument to 'Print' Op, not Tensor("embedding_lookup:0", shape=(300,), dtype=float32).
```

I have also tried the basic python print functionality. This results in 
printing

```
0   UNK Tensor("embedding_lookup:0", shape=(300,), dtype=float32)
1   the Tensor("embedding_lookup_1:0", shape=(300,), dtype=float32)
```

Any pointers as to how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What exactly do you want to print to the export file? The contents of ```embeddings_to_file```, which will be something like ```["a", "b", "c"]```?

Comment: I am trying to print ( [word_index], [word], [embedding for that word]) to a file. (e.g. may be to use these embeddings for a different project ).